# Mute NSAssert warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

I compiled my project with `-Weverything` and I see that all the `NSAssert` calls have the warning

> must specify at least one argument for '...' parameter of variadic macro

`NSAssert(NO, @"This class cannot be instantiated!");`

The correct fix would be to add a `nil` argument to all statements but I would prefer just to mute this warning. Is it possible?

cheers

Comment: I was thinking there was an NSAssert0, but for some silly reason there isn't.

Comment: `-Weverything` is for crazy people. It's pretty difficult to turn on warnings for projects that already have lots of code. If you want to use all the warnings, fix them correctly using a `nil`. Making workarounds for warnings is silly - if you don't like the warning, just turn it off.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score -3):

Add the following parameters to your Other C flags in XCode build settings which turns off all NSAssert in your project:

```
-DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1
```